# Stochastic Integral Computation

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I would like to compute
$\int |dW|$
where $W$ is a Wiener process. I know that this is a divergent integral by the following argument:

$
1 = \sum |W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}|^2 < max|W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}|\times\sum |W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}|
$

where $t_i \in [0,1]$ and $max|W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}|$ tends to $0$ as $t_{i+1}\rightarrow t_{i}$.
The divergent summation can be interpreted as the arc-length of the brownian motion curve. However, I would like to be able to explicitly compute it.

In addition, it seems to me a little counterintuitive because from the other hand I have computed $E(|dW|)$ and the result is finite. Even more, it is not hard to prove that $\int_0^T dW = W_T$ (also convergent). This leads to the conclusion that the modulus has a deep impact on the computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brownian motion has infinite first variation for any interval with probability $1$, that is the series
$$
\sum |W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}| 
$$
diverges when $\max{|t_{i+1} - t_i|} \to 0$.
So if you use that as definition of arc length it is always infinity.
However, the so called second variation, or quadratic variation, you write is always finite:
$$
\sum |W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}|^2 = T, \textrm{ when } \max{|t_{i+1} - t_i|} \to 0.
$$
Where $T=b-a$ is the length of the interval $[a,b], a=t_0 < t_1 \ldots < t_N = b $ you are summing over.
I guess you can see that as some sort of generalized length of the second order. At least I like to see it that way in practical calculations.

Edit: Ok, I think I know what you mean now.
You know that the first variation of the Brownian motion is infinite, but at the same time you know that
$$
 |\Delta W| = |W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_{i}}|
$$
is distributed like
$$
 |W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_{i}}| \sim |N(0, \Delta t)| = |Z| \cdot \sqrt{\Delta t},
$$
where $\Delta t = t_{i+1} - t_{i}$ and $z \sim N(0, 1)$.
So you get that
$$
 E[|W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_{i}}|] = C \sqrt{\Delta t},
$$
for some constant $C = E[|Z|]$. Therefore you wonder why you can't calculate the first variation as the sum of this over all small $\sqrt{\Delta t}$?

In general you are not allowed to move the expectation inside the limit. We have
$$
E[\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sum |W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}|] = E[\infty] = \infty,
$$
If we cheat and still put the expectation inside the limit, we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} E[\sum |W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}|] &=& \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sum E[|W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}|] = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} C \cdot \sum \sqrt{\Delta t} 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
However, this too happens to go to $\infty$ as well from what I can see. Put $\Delta t=1/n$ and assume for simplicity that the interval in question is $[0,1]$, then the last limit is
$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} C \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{\Delta t} = \lim_{n \to \infty} C \cdot n \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \to \infty.
$$
So in this case we get infinity even if we cheat and put the expectation inside the limit (which is not allowed in general).
So I still don't get how you get a finite value.

Comment: I  agree with everything you said but I still want a different argument to justify that the first variation is not bounded. Why if E(|dW|) is bounded the first variation is not?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by the notation $E(|dW|)$ and how did you calculate this? This, I interpret as the first variation you talk about, which is infinite.  If you make some sort of discretization and sum, then you will always end up with a finite value even though it gets larger when the grid spacing goes to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I am starting with this topic so you might find mystakes there and there but I computed the expectation value as follows: $E(|dW|)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx=\sqrt{2/\pi}$. On the other hand, in Willmott Option Pricing Mathematical Models and Computation pag 224 equation (13.2) says (without any explicit computation) that the integral gives $\sqrt{2/\pi}$

Comment: Should I use the folded normal distribution? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution)
In that case I still get the same result  $E(|dW|)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$

Comment: Might you clarify my previous comment? I would be really appreciated.

Comment: You miss the extra factor $\sqrt{dt}$ I mention above.You have formally $$
E(|dW|) = E[|X|]\sqrt{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sqrt{dt}.
$$ 
Then you are supposed to sum over all those dt making up the interval (as in my answer). This sum is infinite.